# Is there an Apache Arrow equivalent of the Spark Pandas UDF

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-arrow, python-polars

Spark provides a few different ways to implement [UDFs that consume and return Pandas DataFrames](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html). I am currently using the [cogrouped version](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.PandasCogroupedOps.applyInPandas.html#pyspark.sql.PandasCogroupedOps.applyInPandas) that takes two (co-grouped) Pandas DataFrames as input and returns a third.

For efficient translation between Spark DataFrames and Pandas DataFrames, Spark uses the Apache Arrow memory layout, however transformation is still required to go from Arrow to Pandas and back. I would really like to access the Arrow data directly, as this is how I will ultimately be working with the data in the UDF (using [Polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars)).

It seems wasteful to go from Spark -> Arrow -> Pandas -> Arrow (Polars) on the way in and the reverse on the return.

Comment: That's an interesting question. All we would need is to be able to go `spark -> arrow -> spark`, as polars has mostly zero copy interop with arrow.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import polars as pl

sql_context = SQLContext(spark)

data = [('James',[1, 2]),]
spark_df = sql_context.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = ["name","properties"])

df = pl.from_arrow(pa.Table.from_batches(spark_df._collect_as_arrow()))

print(df)
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────┬────────────┐
│ name  ┆ properties │
│ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ list[i64]  │
╞═══════╪════════════╡
│ James ┆ [1, 2]     │
└───────┴────────────┘
```